# Discord.py Id to member

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a list of id's and I want to get the list of members. how can I do it?
i did try this

```
        id_list=[]
        for i in amounts :
            if amounts[i] == 0 :
                id_list.append(i)
        for id in id_list:
            members = [discord.utils.get(bot.get_all_members(), id=id) for id in id_list]
            for member in members :
                await remove(member , mover ) #probleme here mover is a role


async def remove( member: discord.Member, role: discord.Role):
    await member.remove_roles(role)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is different from the code that you've given. To get a specific member, you can do:

```py
member = discord.utils.get(bot.get_all_members(), id=MEMBER_ID_HERE)
```

Or if you have the list of IDs:

```py
id_list = [112233445566778899, 224466881133557799 # etc...
members = [m for m in bot.get_all_members() if m.id in id_list]
```

**Post-edit:**
You're able to get all members in a guild that don't have a specific role, and remove the role like this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def remove(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    members = [m for m in ctx.guild.members if role in m.roles]
    for m in members:
        await m.remove_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f"Successfully removed {role.mention} from all users!")
```

**Calling another async function from a command:**

```py
async def remove(role: discord.Role):
    id_list = [112233445566778899, 224466881133557799 # etc...
    members = [m for m in bot.get_all_members() if m.id in id_list]
    for m in members:
        await m.remove_roles(role)

@bot.command()
async def cmd(ctx, role: discord.Role = None):
    if not role:
        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=112233445566778899)
    await remove(role) # you can also pass ctx if you need it in the function
```

---

**References:**

- [`Client.get_all_members()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_all_members)
- [`utils.get()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get)
- [`Guild.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.members)
- [`Member.roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.roles)
- [`Member.remove_roles()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.remove_roles)

Comment: thank you that help a lot, sorry for my previous code. Here is what I'm trying to do :
*

Comment: I'm trying to remove the role "mover" from the members in the list.

Comment: the problem is there is no ctx since there is no command . also your code will remove the role from all users instead of specific users in a list

Comment: Thanks a lot, but one more problem  to actually call this function :
 await remove(???)  i mean how can i implement the role like @+role or role or 'role' in all cases the is an error . i have the name of the role but i can't call the function.  Ty you helped a lot

Comment: @ChadiChaddi I edited my answer to show how you can call an asynchronous function from a command ^

Comment: Can i set a default value in `async def cmd(ctx, role: discord.Role): ` i mean like role:discord.Role=a_role

Comment: @ChadiChaddi You can set the default value to `None`, and then in the command, if the value is `None`, you can set the `role` variable to some role in the server. See the edited answer ^

Comment: actually i solved it using `role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='mover')`
Thank you :)